# STRUTS2 - Value stack values are passed in URL!

Tags: java, struts2

I need a solution to hide or encode the "Value Stack" Values in URL.

The 'Value stack' values shows in URL if in struts.xml file the result was a jsp:
example

```
 <action name="actionName" class="ActionClass">
      <result name="resultReturned">page.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

I found 1 solution. 
1) when we redirect to another ACTION, the values doesn't show in url.
Example:

```
 <action...>
    <result name="resultReturned" type="redirectAction">ActionNameX</result>
    ..
    </action>

<action name="ActionNameX" >
...
</action>
```

Is there any other solution?

Thank you !

Comment: Include your login form's action and JSP code in your question. Value Stack values are not passed through the URL. If parameters are being passed in the URL it is because your form is set to GET and not POST. Login forms should never be set to GET.

Comment: Ok, that worked! by default it considered it GET..
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean your form values are passed in the URL? Which in turn are set on the action and then become part of the value stack... Just use a plain html form with method="POST" although remember that hiding the URL values can make book marking difficult and really just makes you feel better, there is nothing more secure about it perhaps less as it may lull you into a false sense of security.

Comment: Secure from who? What is it exactly you want to prevent?

Comment: I'll give you an example:
When the user logs in, if he fails to log in ( wrong password - LOCKED user - DEACTIVATED user...) based on my struts.xml, it should go to login.jsp ==> in this scenario the username and password are shown in the URL.

Comment: On the other hand, if I use my suggested solution (in my question) the problem is the value stack is emptied and I need some Values (notificationMethod, username)

Comment: The easiest solution is to just have a password setter and no getter in your action. Struts2 only reads from public getters (well public fields too).